# Silence when loading lightgbm model in python from pickle

Tags: python, json, lightgbm

I have a question concerning the loading of lightgbm model previously saved as pickle.

If I train, save and load a model as pickle in the same script, when loading the pickle nothing will be printed.
With this script, nothing is printed when loading the model.

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
import pickle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
import lightgbm as lgb                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

params = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
'objective': 'regression',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
'verbose': -1,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
'num_leaves': 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}  

X = np.random.rand(100,2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Y = np.ravel(np.random.rand(100,1))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
lgbm = lgb.train(params, lgb.Dataset(X,label=Y),num_boost_round=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

f = open('test_pickle.pkl','wb')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
pickle.dump(lgbm,f)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
f.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

f = open('test_pickle.pkl','r')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
pickle.load(f)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
f.close()`
```

If after that I open a new script and load the model like this :

```
import pickle
f = open('test_pickle.pkl','r')
pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

there will be a print like this :

`[LightGBM] [Info] Finished loading 2 models`

My question is : how can I do to not have the printing when the model is loaded not in the script where it was saved ?

Thanks in advance

Ben

Comment: Reading mode should be "rb" since writing mode was binary. 
Furthermore, I was not able to reproduce your printing problem with lightgbm version '2.3.1'.